# Calculate day difference between date present in file and today date

Tags: unix, awk, sed

In the data below, 3rd column represent the date of subscription and last column represent the total day till today (inclusive subscription day and total day).

```
'919123456789','DATA','20180919','20181011','Status_Subscribed','23'
'919999999999','DATA','20180924','20181011','Status_Subscribed','18'
```

I need to find out if there is any incorrect data in the last column after days calculation on the basis of 3rd column and today date.

Please assist.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Even if the last column is correct today, it will be wrong tomorrow. You might want to scrap it and always calculate the days.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the strftime function (GNU awk, not the posix one)

```
awk -F "[', \t]+" 'NF > 0 {
   CompareDate = strftime( "%Y%m%d", systime() - $7 * 86400)
   if ( CompareDate == $4 ) print "Compliant"
    else print "Line " NR " is wrong. Estimation is " CompareDate " and info is " $4
   }' YourFile
```

Comment: Command is not working properly. Below is the output :  Line 1 is wrong. Estimation is 20180918 and info is 20180919
Line 2 is wrong. Estimation is 20180923 and info is 20180924. It seems like it is not including today date.

Comment: depend on your reference date count for the 6th column. adapt the $7 with ( $7 -1 ) in this case. Code is there for explaination of how you can do it, not for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) using the `date` program:

```
today=$(date "+%F")
while read -r line; do 
   IFS="," read -r x x d x x t <<<$line;
   date=$(date -d  "${d//\'/} + ${t//\'/} days" "+%F")
   [[  "$date" != "$today" ]] && echo "Bad line: ${line}"
done
```